# SpringBoot AutoConfigurationSorter 1.5.8 bug on Linux?

Tags: spring-boot

So I deployed a build that runs perfectly on my windows machine to a Linux box earlier this morning and when I tried to start the service I got the error below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration
```

So I copied all of the libs from the target machine to my windows machine and ran the application from a windows command prompt.  The application started fine.

So I eventually remote debugged the application and came up with a very interesting issue that has got my head scratching.

But before I went further I switched on -verbose to make sure the class in question was being loaded from the same jar in both windows and linux.

```
[Loaded org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration from file:/apps/IRDrsudbld/<project structure>/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar]
```

And it is.

So when I debug in linux and look at the metadata for the two classes

this = {AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass@3645}
className = "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration"
metadataReaderFactory = {ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory@3637}
autoConfigurationMetadata = {AutoConfigurationMetadataLoader$PropertiesAutoConfigurationMetadata@3611}

It states the following

"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration.AutoConfigureBefore" -> "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"

"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration.AutoConfigureAfter" -> "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration,
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration,
**org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,**
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration"

But the line in bold is completely wrong as the 1.5.8 source code has the annotations below.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({CacheManager.class})
@ConditionalOnBean({CacheAspectSupport.class})
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = {CacheManager.class},name = {"cacheResolver"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CacheProperties.class})
@AutoConfigureBefore({HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter({CouchbaseAutoConfiguration.class, HazelcastAutoConfiguration.class, 
RedisAutoConfiguration.class})
@Import({CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheConfigurationImportSelector.class})
public class CacheAutoConfiguration {
```

Has anyone seen an issue like this before as I am completely mystified as to what is happening here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After debugging the code it appears that one of the internal shaded jar files contains a spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties which is for spring boot 2.  When the application is executed on linux this jar file is loaded after the spring boot autoconfigure one and replaces the

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration.AutoConfigureAfter

Property with one that is not valid for the spring boot version in my application.

At least I have found out what the problem is.